# I need to match Sheet1 Column A to Sheet2 Column A if they match then copy Sheet2 Column B to Sheet1 Column I

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vba

I need to match Sheet1 Column A  to Sheet2 Column A if they match then copy Sheet2 Column B to Sheet1 Column I

Answer (score 0, accepted):

insert the following formula to the cell where you would like the data to be displayed. Obviously you can populate this formula to as many rows as you need for your data.

=IF(Sheet1!A1=Sheet2!A1,Sheet2!B1,"")